# Finding a probability function for the max and expectations

Tags: probability, expectation, uniform-distribution

I am new here I need help of the enlightened to solve a couple of probability problems. I've been trying to tackle them but so far been unsuccessful.

**1)** Three independent random variables $x, y, z$ ~ Uniform [1, 3]. Find the probability function for the maximum of X, Y, Z.

As far as I understood i need to find $f(c) = \mathbb{P}(\max(x,y,z) \leq c)$ for any $c$ ∈ ℝ. How to solve it?

**2)** Two independent random variables $x, y$~ Uniform [0, 1]. Find the probability function of the random variable $z = x-y$ Compute the expectation of $z$.

Same as above, do I need to find $f(c) = \mathbb{P} ( z \leq c)= \mathbb{P} (x-y \leq c)$ for any $c$ ∈ ℝ? I have no idea how to compute the expectation, though. How to solve them?

Would much appreciate your help, many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Jose, thanks for welcoming. I edited the formulas, especially spacings. Will do my best to write formulas according MathJax rules.

Comment: You did **not** use MathJax at all.

Comment: Uhh, sorry, now it should be correct. Apologies.

Comment: It's traditional to use capital letters for probability distribution functions.  Whoever edited those $F$s to $f$s should put them back to $F$.

Answer (score 0):

(1) The complicated answer would be to tell you to look up "order statistics".  However, this is a bit simpler.  The maximum is $\le c$ if and only if each of the random variables is $\le c$.  Since they are independent, that's just the probability that $X\le c$ times the probability that $Y\le c$ times the probability that $Z\le c$.  But each of those is $0$ if $c\le 1$, $(c-1)/2$ if $1\le c \le 3$, and $1$ if $c\ge 3$.  Thus, the probability distribution function $F(c)$ for $max(X,Y,Z)$ is $0$ if $c\le 1$, $(c-1)^3/8$ if $1\le c\le 3$ and $1$ if $c\ge 3$.

If in fact what you needed was the density $f$ of $max(X,Y,Z)$ that's easy now since it's just the derivative of $F$, i.e., the density is $\frac{3(c-1)^2}{8}$ if $1\le c \le 3$ and $0$ otherwise.

(2) You don't actually need to compute the distribution of $Z$ here.  Just use that expectation is linear.  $E(Z)=E(X-Y)=E(X)-E(Y)=0.5-0.5=0$.